# WinAppDriver, Python, How To Select Elements On Popup Window

Tags: python, winforms, popup, appium, winappdriver

I am automating UI tests on a Windows 10 application with WinAppDriver in Python and not able to select elements on popup windows.  If someone have this working, would you mind sharing your experience?  I was able to get this sample code to run https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/tree/master/Samples/Python.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the popup window is not within the context of your current selected application.

You probably need to switch to a desktop session, find your popup, and then switch to it.

I handle this for robotframework so you may be able to use some of the python backend code here:

https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba/blob/master/src/Zoomba/DesktopLibrary.py#L298